# Mysql_insert_id() unable to get value from first query and use it in second query..both queries used for insertion but in two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use the **MySQL_insert_id** to get a value from first query which has an Auto-Increment with the name of **PropertyImageID** which is the last column in my **properties** table and also i have **PropertyImageID** same in my second table which is **propertyimages** first column and use it in second query for inserting the values in second table.

But its giving this error message:

> Warning: mysql_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be 
>   resource, Boolean given in on..line 31

here is my code (i didn't write the Auto-Increment Column in my query):

```
<?php
    require_once('db.php');
    @$PropertyName=$_POST['pname'];
    @$PropertyStatus=$_POST['pstatus'];
    @$PropertyID=$_POST['propertyid'];
    if(isset($_FILES['file_upload']))
    {

    $propertyquery="INSERT INTO properties(PropertyID, PropertyName,   PropertyStatus) 
    VALUES('$PropertyID', '$PropertyName', '$PropertyStatus')";
    $propertyqueryrun=mysql_query($propertyquery) or die(mysql_error());

      if($propertyqueryrun)
         {
         echo '<br><br> The Property Information Insertion was Successfully';
         }
              else
         {
                  echo '<br><br> Property Insertion Failed';
         }

    $shuff=str_shuffle("ABD6565LSLFKDSAJFD");

    mkdir("upload/$shuff");

    $files=$_FILES['file_upload'];


    for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++)
    {
      $name=$files['name'][$x];

      $tmp_name=$files['tmp_name'][$x];

         if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "upload/$shuff/".$name))
         {
        $result=mysql_query($propertyquery)------>First query;

        $id=mysql_insert_id($result) or die(mysql_error());

         $imagequery="INSERT INTO propertyimages(PropertyImageID, ImageName, 

    ImagePath)   VALUES('**$id**', '$name', 'upload/$name')";

             $imagequeryrun=mysql_query($imagequery);

             echo 'Image '. $name .' Uploaded Successfully <br>';
         }
         else
         {
             echo 'uploading images failed failed';
         }

    }

    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>PropertyName:<br /></label>
    <input type="text" name="pname" /><br />
    <label>PropertyStatus:<br /></label>
    <input type="text" name="pstatus" /><br />
    <label>PropertyID:<br /></label>
    <input type="text" name="propertyid" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="file_upload[]" multiple="multiple" / size="7"><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
    </form>
    <a href="home.php">Display Images</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is you mysql_insert_id() i cant find

Comment: That means that `mysql_query` failed.

Comment: @YadavChetan Use ctrl+f in your browser `$id=mysql_insert_id($propertyqueryrun)`

Comment: Did you read documentation about [mysql_instert_id](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should declare it just after insert query and you specified wrong parameter to it

```
<?php
    require_once('db.php');
    @$PropertyName=$_POST['pname'];
    @$PropertyStatus=$_POST['pstatus'];
    @$PropertyID=$_POST['propertyid'];
    if(isset($_FILES['file_upload']))
    {

    $propertyquery="INSERT INTO properties(PropertyID,PropertyName,PropertyStatus) 
    VALUES('$PropertyID', '$PropertyName', '$PropertyStatus')";
    $propertyqueryrun=mysql_query($propertyquery) or die(mysql_error());
   $insert_id=mysql_insert_id();
      if($propertyqueryrun)
         {
         echo '<br><br> The Property Information Insertion was Successfully';
         }
              else
         {
                  echo '<br><br> Property Insertion Failed';
         }

    $shuff=str_shuffle("ABD6565LSLFKDSAJFD");

    mkdir("upload/$shuff");

    $files=$_FILES['file_upload'];


    for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++)
    {
      $name=$files['name'][$x];

      $tmp_name=$files['tmp_name'][$x];

         if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "upload/$shuff/".$name))
         {
         $id= $insert_id;

         $imagequery="INSERT INTO propertyimages(PropertyImageID,ImageName, 

    ImagePath)   VALUES('$id','$name','$name')";

             $imagequeryrun=mysql_query($imagequery);

             echo 'Image '. $name .' Uploaded Successfully <br>';
         }
         else
         {
             echo 'uploading images failed failed';
         }

    }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: i edit the code as you written but i got  'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1';

Comment: then error in insert query

Comment: try now i have edited the query

Comment: ya got it million thanks, but whenever i am entering the wrong value into the boxes and it checks for validation in DB one number is authomatically skiped when next time i insert a valid values it skipe one.. how to solve this ???????

Comment: @user2279037 you should validate before entering into database

Comment: clientside is enough or both client and serverside???????

Comment: @user2279037 client side enough if Javascript is not disable but in case of javascript disable then server side is also required so for security you should do both

Comment: @user2279037 your welcome, keep going

Answer (score 2):

No need to pass argument in `mysql_insert_id()`. You can get the `last inserted id` using without passing `$propertyqueryrun` value.

```
$id = mysql_insert_id() or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$id=mysql_insert_id($propertyqueryrun) or die(mysql_error());
```

to

```
$id=mysql_insert_id() or die(mysql_error());
```

No need to pass query parameter, it requires only optional link parameter